# POST working with HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, post, http-status-code-405

I'm building a web app running on a Tomcat server and ran into some issues when switching things over to use HTTPS. I'm using Postman to send the JSON objects, and I receive the correct response when using HTTP. But when I included:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>myapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

in my web.xml file, I get a 405: Method Not Allowed. From the headers I get back, it looks like an OPTIONS request was sent instead:

Allow →POST,OPTIONS
Cache-Control →private
Content-Length →0
Date →Wed, 24 Jan 2018 04:53:36 GMT
Expires →Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1

Normally I'd assume it was a CORS issue, but I'm using Postman, not a browser, so that should rule it out, right? Is there anything about SSL certificates that affects POST requests? This is the first time I've generated one so it's uncharted territory for me. GET requests still work fine.

Here is my REST controller class:

```
@Singleton
@Path("generate/")
public class ItineraryController {

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ItineraryController.class);

   @POST
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Itinerary getItinerary(ItineraryRequest request) {
        log.info("Creating itinerary");
        return createTestItinerary();
   }
}
```

Comment: because when you get the license of ssl.. you need to define each url which go though https...

Comment: You need to configure a HTTPS connector in Tomcat and bind a SSL certificate to the connector. Then you will be able to communicate using HTTPS.